# Odoo 10 received custom email template rendering incorrectly

Tags: python, email, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to send an email from a custom module but an error like this occured: "Failed to render template"

I actually received an email but the body of content was not the same. Here's the code in XML file:

```
<odoo>
<data noupdate="1">
    <record id="task_email_template_one" model="mail.template">
        <field name="name">Task Email</field>
        <field name="email_from">${object.user_email| safe}</field>
        <field name="email_to">${object.user_id}</field>
        <field name="subject">The Task ${object.name}</field>
        <field name="lang">${object.lang}</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="task.model_project_task"/>
        <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
            <p>
                    Sample Message                  
            </p>
            ]]>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
```

It seems that the template being used was from mail_template.xml

```
<template id="message_user_assigned">
      <p>Dear <t t-esc="object.user_id.sudo().name"/>,</p>
      <p>You have been assigned to the <t t-esc="object._description.lower()"/> <t t-esc="object.name_get()[0][1]"/>.</p>
      <p>
          <a t-att-href="'/mail/view?model=%s&amp;res_id=%s' % (object._name, object.id)"
                  style="background-color: #9E588B; margin-top: 10px; padding: 10px; text-decoration: none; color: #fff; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 16px;">
                View <t t-esc="object._description.lower()"/>
          </a>
      </p>
      <p style="color:#9E588B;">Powered by <a href="https://www.odoo.com">Odoo</a>.</p>
</template>
```

The custom email template wasn't used instead it uses the ones from mail_template, how can I possibly resolve this?

Edited: I made some changes from my XML file, there were no errors but still the email's body content wasn't the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes,

1. In the `email_from` there is a typo. Instead of `${object.user.id.email| safe}` it can be `${object.user_id.email| safe}`
2. model_id must be according to the model XML id (`project.model_project_task`) not `task.model_project_task`
3. Additionally, you missed the `email` of the user in the `email_to`

Check below the improved mail template.

```
    <data>
        <record id="task_email_template_one" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Task Email</field>
            <field name="email_from">${object.user_id.email| safe}</field>
            <field name="email_to">${object.user_id.email}</field>
            <field name="subject">The Task ${object.name}</field>
            <field name="lang">${object.lang}</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_task"/>
            <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
                <p>
                        Sample Message
                </p>
                ]]>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
```

Because you added the `noupdate=1`, delete the mail template, and upgrade the module again in order to apply the changes, you should remove the `noupdate=1` when you are developing the module :)